# Write Mac OS X apps with Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, macos

I just came upon this article here which can turn your day to day visual basic app to run on mac os x. Here is the link: http://mac.sillydog.org/dev/visual_studio.php The thing I don't get is that the author doesn't tell us specifically what to download, and where to get all the files. He's a bit vague... Can anyone make this clearer to me?

BTW: I am using VB.NET although the author uses C#. I think it  will still work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [.NET Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)
- [Mono Framework for Mac OS X](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)
- [wx.NET](http://wxnet.sourceforge.net/)

The [Mac OSX build of wx.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxnet/files/wxnet/0.8.0/wx.NET_Carbon.zip/download) is called Carbon. The readme says:

> This package is a contribution of wx.NET user Matthias Fuchs, who wrote:
>
> Hi,
>
> as i didn't find a binary package for Mac OS X I created my own ;-)
>
> I've built wx.NET for Mac OS 10.5.7. I used wxWidgets 2.8.10 and created a Mac OS X Framework Bundle.
> The zip file includes a "wxWidgets.framework" folder, which must be installed into /Library/Frameworks/ on the root partition of MacOS X. I also tried to copy the wx.NET.dll to Mono's GAC, but mono can't find the wx-c.dylib. But I think it is ok, that users can just put the wx.NET files into their bin/debug/release folders.

Follow those instructions and use the Windows Mono build of wx.NET when testing on the same machine as Visual Studio and the Mac OSX build when you deploy it.

Comment: yea, but what version of wx.Net do you need? And where do you get the wx.net.config file?

Comment: I edited my answer to be a little more detailed. The wx.NET.dll.config file is included in the wx.NET package.

Comment: Actually, [Carbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(API)) is an Apple API for Mac programming that allowed rapid porting of old Mac OS 8 and 9 software to Mac OS X, and has nothing to do with .NET or wx.NET. The [Mac OSX build of wx.NET is called "wx.NET_Carbon"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxnet/files/wxnet/0.8.0/wx.NET%5FCarbon.zip/download), not "Carbon"

Answer (score 0):

The important part is [the mono framework](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). It looks like you need [this release](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).